How to run a scrapy Crawl Spider from terminal?
i made a code from a tutorial, its practically the same. The guy run it from terminal with a .csv file as output, but when i run it, it appears a lot of options for running the file but doesnt make anything that i want but doesnt throw any error apparently. What am i doing wrong?, i run it like this:
(.venv) PS C:\Users\dodge\PycharmProjects\Scraper> scrapy runspider merclibre.py -o mercadolibre.csv -t csv

and the output is this:
2024-12-25 19:47:05 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.12.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
2024-12-25 19:47:05 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 5.3.0.0, 
libxml2 2.11.7
, cssselect 1.2.0, parsel 1.9.1, w3lib 2.2.1, Twisted 24.11.0, Python 
3.12.6 (tags/
v3.12.6:a4a2d2b, Sep  6 2024, 20:11:23) [MSC v.1940 64 bit (AMD64)], 
pyOpenSSL 24.3
.0 (OpenSSL 3.4.0 22 Oct 2024), cryptography 44.0.0, Platform Windows- 
11-10.0.22631-SP0
Usage
=====
scrapy runspider [options] <spider_file>

Run the spider defined in the given file

Options
=======
-h, --help            show this help message and exit
-a NAME=VALUE         set spider argument (may be repeated)
-o FILE, --output FILE
                    append scraped items to the end of FILE (use - for
                    stdout), to define format set a colon at the end of 
the    
                    output URI (i.e. -o FILE:FORMAT)
-O FILE, --overwrite-output FILE
                    dump scraped items into FILE, overwriting any 
existing     
                    file, to define format set a colon at the end of 
the       
                    output URI (i.e. -O FILE:FORMAT)

Global Options
--------------
--logfile FILE        log file. if omitted stderr will be used
-L LEVEL, --loglevel LEVEL
                    log level (default: DEBUG)
--nolog               disable logging completely
--profile FILE        write python cProfile stats to FILE
--pidfile FILE        write process ID to FILE
-s NAME=VALUE, --set NAME=VALUE
                    set/override setting (may be repeated)
--pdb                 enable pdb on failure


You need to show your code.
